# How I get a reference to the last-actions's stack?

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto

I want to develop an Add-in for Microsoft.Word that will allow you to undo one of all last actions that made in the application that is running now - not necessarily the last action.
a shape, and paste a picture. For example: I wrote some words, added
now I want to undo writing the words without undoing the other actions: adding shapes and pasting a picture.

For that, I need a reference to the last-actions's stack 
I opened Word 2016 VSTO Add-in project.

I searched and found only those methods: 
Doc.Undo() that remove the last action.
startUndoRecored() that enabled undoing block of actions which done by the programmer together.

Now, my question is how I get a reference to the last-actions's stack? Or maybe you have another idea to do that?
Thanks

Comment: This is not supported in Word. Word doesn't write these things to a "stack*; it keeps "scratch" and "temp" files to track actions in a document and access isn't provided to the developer. You'd need to keep your own log and use the log to perform the Undo actions you want to rollback.

Comment: @CindyMeister Do you know of any articles that expand on this? Sounds interesting.

Comment: @Chris No, I've no idea whether anyone has ever actually *done* this - it would certainly be non-trivial. It's just the only possibility that occurs to me.

Comment: @CindyMeister No, I mean the scratch and temp files used to keep undo history. I don't have any intention of trying to circumvent the API (I'm sure it would be a huge pain), I'm just curious.

Comment: @Chris No, I can't recall having ever seen any articles about those files, either. The little I know comes from chatting with people on the Word team - many, many years ago (prior to docx file format). Uh, I even remember when Undo was introduced, and when it went from a single action to 100 actions, and from there to "unlimited"...